# PHP and database with blob images 403ing on some IDs

Tags: php, database

When I use `$qry="SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=2";` , the website returns a `403 Error` and can't reconnect.

It only seems to work while `id=1` and if I use `id=2` (or anything greater than 1), it crashes.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    <div id="block_dem">
                <div id="image1" onclick="image1()">
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("eee","eee","eee");
                mysql_select_db("eee",$con);
                $qry="SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=1";
                $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo '<img height="100%" width="100%" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[2].'"> ';
                }
                mysql_close($con);  
                mysql_close();?>
                </div></div>
                <div id="block_dem">
                <div id="image1" onclick="image1()">
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("eee","eee","eee");
                mysql_select_db("eee",$con);
                $qry="SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=2";
                $result=mysql_query($qry,$con);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo '<img height="100%" width="100%" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[2].'"> ';
                }
                mysql_close($con);  
                 mysql_close();?>
                </div></div>
```

Comment: I would try the same query directly in the database to try and see any errors. Maybe the image size is too large.

Comment: found the problem...Some images can be uploaded...some others can't.

Answer (score 0):

Y would highly recommend to use PDO or mysqli instead of mysql (already deprecated). Try to add to every mysql function at the end:

```
 or die(mysql_error())
```

And see what you get